# Translating "to care for each other" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, latin-to-english-translation

I have a friend. She and I have strong loyalties to each other -- we have a semi-unspoken agreement to be always forthright with and always supportive of one another, and I want to express this sentiment in Latin.

My supposition is: "Foedus constat; utri nostrum curare" which I translate literally as "Our pact stands; to care for the other of us." Or, in more colloquial English "We made a pact; to care for each other."

Is there a translation which makes more (or any) sense? I'm quite unsure as to whether my translation would be understood in Latin.

Comment: First impression: For reciprocal actions, one typically uses inter se (or, in your case, inter nos). Using utri nostrum for this seems very odd, though perhaps you've come across a similar expression somewhere.

Comment: @cnread: What about "alter-alterum" = "each other"; though a case-ending change may be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with *Foedus constat; utri nostrum curare*.

But I think I prefer the Vulgate's somewhat metaphorical version of this, *Alter alterius onera portate* (Carry each other's burdens). I mention it because you (or others) might agree.

This could be adapted to *Foedus constat: alterum alterius onera portare*, or just simply, *Alter alterius onera portemus* (Let's carry each others burdens.)

Comment: I like your non-literal approach here and your choice of passages from the Vulgate to use as a model. If you use the infinitive portare, though, note that the nominative alter needs to be changed to accusative alterum, because it's the subject of the infinitive.

Comment: … or *alteram* if both friends are female.

Comment: @cnread Thanks! I'll fix it.